# AngularJS ng-class filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-class

I have a simple filter on my ng-class that looks for a rid that begins with '1A' in my ng-repeat of service in services

```
ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':rid.indexOf('1A') > -1}"
```

If the rid begins with 1A then the class of couldBeWrong should be applied

I have also tried various variations such as

```
class="{'couldBeWrong':rid.indexOf('1A') > -1}"
```

and

```
ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':service.rid.indexOf('1A') > -1}"
```

EDIT : Based on accepted answer, here is my solution

Added to controller

```
$scope.getClass = function(field){
    if(field.indexOf('1L') > -1){
        return true;//or you can modify as per your need
    }else{
        return false;//you can modify as per your need   
    }
}
```

and the NG-CLASS in the repeat

```
ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':getClass(service.rid)}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':getClass(rid)}"
```

In Controller

```
$scope.getClass = function(){
  if(rid.indexOf('1A') > -1){
    return true;//or you can modify as per your need
  }else{
    return false;//you can modify as per your need   
  }
}
```

Comment: Your forget to close brackets: ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':getClass(rid)}"

Comment: yeah @VitaliyAndrusishyn because I didnt run it :)

Comment: I based my answer on this, just tweaked it a little.. adding to OP now

Answer (score 1):

You seem to forget the closing braces. It should be like this:

```
ng-class="{'couldBeWrong':rid.indexOf('1A') > -1}"
```

Comment: Could you provide the template plus controller. With what you have provided, it is expected to work